# Inconsistent App Store ratings stars representation

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ios-appstore, ratings

In the iTunes App Store for iPhone, the rating is often displayed near the application's icon. Sometimes, when there are no ratings, the empty stars have an orange outline and sometimes they don't.

Is there a significance to having the orange outline? What might the outline signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would appear to just be a styling issue where some of the stars on different category page/tabs have the orange surround and some don't.

If you find an application without the orange surround in a page then select it to take you into the app description, suddenly it will have the orange surround.